# Design console of Oracle 11gR2PS1 and 11gR2PS2 are same?

Tags: oracle11g

My question is that either OIM design console of Oracle 11gR2PS1 and 11gR2PS2  are same or different??
please help me

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the OIM design console.(?)
Of course they are going to be different but the PS2 version should contain bug fixes, feature enhancements, etc...
For a list of differences see the OIM upgrade white paper: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40329_01/doc.1112/e48646/upg_psone_oim.htm#A1098521